# Limit Netgear Nighthawk AC1750 to given WAN IPs

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall

I have a Netgear Nighthawk AC1750 router, and have SSH, HTTP, and several other ports forwarded to a server.  It is not for public use, and will only be accessed by me.  I've recently had 60,000 hits several IPs from India and China, and am getting nervous.

Could the router be configured to only accept connections from pre-specified IPs?

Comment: Welcome to the internet. You may not know yet, but port scans and automatic hacking are a normal everyday occurrence. In case your systems are properly secured (which is absolutely imperative when providing services), there’s nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything in the router manual allowing firewalling based on source ip, but there may be other solutions, like firewall software configuration on the server, or a real hardware firewall.

If you have just one server, I would recommend firewall software configuration on the server.

Comment: Thanks.  I've since contacted Netgear, and I can't white or black list specific IPs.  Any recommendations on one that does?

Comment: I like pfsense, which is an open source firewall operating system. It is fairly simple to set up, can be done on old hardware, it has an extensive feature set (including a plugin to block regions or countries), and I found it easy to use. That said, you can still go with a SOHO firewall from netgear, cisco, or zyxel.